# Setting Linux account limit value descriptors unlimited /etc/security/limits.conf

Tags: admin, rhel

I have tried to set some resource limits on my rhel server modifying the /etc/security/limits.conf to the below.

```
#<domain>      <type>  <item>         <value>
#
#*               hard    rss             10000
#@student        hard    nproc           20
#@faculty        soft    nproc           20
#@faculty        hard    nproc           50
#ftp             hard    nproc           0
#@student        -       maxlogins       4
tctmsv80        hard    stack           8192
tctmsv80        hard    core            unlimited
tctmsv80        hard    descriptors     4096
# End of file
```

When I run the limit command I get the below output

```
[tctmsv80@ip-10-182-1-77 ~]$ limit
cputime      unlimited
filesize     unlimited
datasize     unlimited
stacksize    8192 kbytes
coredumpsize 0 kbytes
memoryuse    unlimited
vmemoryuse   unlimited
descriptors  1024
memorylocked 64 kbytes
maxproc      1024
[tctmsv80@ip-10-182-1-77 ~]$
```

So my stacksize has been changed successfully but my coredumpsize and descriptors has not. Can't for the life of me figure out why. I have tried logging out and back in but the values do not change. I followed this guide

http://singztechmusings.wordpress.com/2011/07/11/ulimit-how-to-permanently-set-kernel-limits-in-linux/

It's also weird because I can change the setting using the CLI

```
[tctmsv80@ip-10-182-1-77 ~]$ limit
cputime      unlimited
filesize     unlimited
datasize     unlimited
stacksize    8192 kbytes
coredumpsize 0 kbytes
memoryuse    unlimited
vmemoryuse   unlimited
descriptors  1024
memorylocked 64 kbytes
maxproc      1024

[tctmsv80@ip-10-182-1-77 ~]$ limit core unlimited
[tctmsv80@ip-10-182-1-77 ~]$ limit
cputime      unlimited
filesize     unlimited
datasize     unlimited
stacksize    8192 kbytes
coredumpsize unlimited
memoryuse    unlimited
vmemoryuse   unlimited
descriptors  1024
memorylocked 64 kbytes
maxproc      1024
```

But when I log in and out of thta user it resets

```
[tctmsv80@ip-10-182-1-77 ~]$ logout
[ec2-user@ip-10-182-1-77 apps]$ su - tctmsv80
Password:
[tctmsv80@ip-10-182-1-77 ~]$ limit
cputime      unlimited
filesize     unlimited
datasize     unlimited
stacksize    8192 kbytes
coredumpsize 0 kbytes
memoryuse    unlimited
vmemoryuse   unlimited
descriptors  1024
memorylocked 64 kbytes
maxproc      1024
```

Comment: Any chance this applies: ssh login and /etc/security/limits.conf consideration
When you set some restriction for users in limits.conf and you login through ssh, then you need to make sure /etc/ssh/sshd_config to have 'usePAM yes'

Comment: Hi Michael thanks for the reply. I have check this paramter and it is set to UsePAM yes

Comment: Anything in the users profile (ie ~/.profile) or any user account startup scripts that may be resetting them? Maybe even /etc/profile (the global one)

Comment: Its a fresh AWS AMI instance which I am have checked and couldn't find any scripts resetting these values. The weird thing is I can use the limit command to change the values but they reset after i log in and out of user tctmsv80. I have updated my question with more detail on this. I have also checked the ~/.profile for the only 2 users on this server and both files are empty

Comment: Please, type "ulimit -a" and post its output here.